# Link MinGW .a static C libraries with GoLink

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, static-libraries, sdl-2

I'm trying to make an SDL2 program with NASM and GoLink just for fun but I can't link SDL2main.a and SDL2 to my executable. I'm on a win64 architecture.

My main.asm

```
[bits 64]

extern ExitProcess

extern SDL_Init
extern SDL_Quit


SDL_INIT_VIDEO equ 0x00000020

section .text

    _start:
        mov rcx, SDL_INIT_VIDEO
        call SDL_Init

        call SDL_Quit

        xor rcx, rcx
        call ExitProcess
```

and this is the way I build my .exe :

```bash
nasm -f win64 main.asm -o main.obj
.\GoLink.exe /console /entry _start /fo prog.exe main.obj kernel32.dll
```

and I get the following error :

```
GoLink.Exe Version 1.0.4.1  Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002-2022   info@goprog.com

Error!
The following symbols were not defined in the object file or files:-
SDL_Init
SDL_Quit
Output file not made
```

My static libs are located in a ./lib folder if it can help.

Comment: If you want to use static, I'd be curious why you have `.a` files and not `.lib` files. Wheer did you get your SDL2 from?

Comment: Ah I just didn't see the comment features. I use the MinGW version because normally I code in C / C++ with gcc under Windows I will try the Visual C/C++ version. And I don't use ld because it's a nightmare to use with Windows

Comment: MinGW's GCC/G++ uses LD as its linker (behind the scenes) when you compile to an executable. GCC can be used for linking purposes even if you aren't using any .C files.

Comment: I know but with nasm I get lots of errors and it was just easier to use GoLink. And it works thank !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GoLink](http://www.godevtool.com/GolinkFrame.htm) doesn't understand the `.a` static library file format that MinGW based tool chains create. If you intend to use GoLink, you will need to get a copy of the SDL2 library that works with the Microsoft tools and linker.

In your case you will want the SDL2 development libraries for Visual C++ on their [download page](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) rather than the MinGW libraries that you are currently using.